# Python: Processing list of arguments on several servers with celery

Tags: python, rabbitmq, celery, message-queue, dask

I am trying to use Celery to process a list of inputs. I'd like to process each input only once. The trouble is that my servers are all part of a supercomputer cluster. I can send each server a single command to start a process. Once that server is scheduled to perform work for my username (which occurs at some random time in the future), it will start that process (so the number of servers running at any time is indeterminant). I'd like all of the servers that are performing work for my username to share the available work until all the required work is done.

I'm confused, though, about how exactly to orchestrate this.

Here's my `app.py`, which outlines the task to be consumed by the servers:

```
from celery import Celery

app = Celery('tasks',
  backend='redis://localhost:6379/0',
  broker='redis://localhost:6379/0')

@app.task
def add(x, y):
  with open('results.txt', 'a') as out:
    out.write(str(x + y) + '\n')
```

Here's the script that schedules the work (`worker.py`):

```
'''Worker node; executes tasks outlined in app.py'''
from app import add

# run the add function and pass in arguments
for i in range(10000):
  result = add.apply_async(args=[1,i]).get()
```

On my local machine, if I run `celery worker -l info -A app` in a terminal, that will start the celery app. If I then run `worker.py`, I see the work being churned through.

How can I make multiple different hosts consume the uncompleted tasks? Each server will have access to a static IP on which Redis will be run. Do I submit the `celery worker -l info -A app` command to each host? If so, will each host magically consume from the uncompleted work when it comes online? I'd be tremendously grateful for any help others can offer with these high-level questions!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer the question above, I created a file named `app.py` and loaded it to a front-end node to which I could ssh. This file outlines the function that individual workers on various servers will process:

```
from celery import Celery

app = Celery('tasks',
  backend='redis://daccssfe.crc.nd.edu:6379/0',
  broker='redis://daccssfe.crc.nd.edu:6379/0')

@app.task
def log(*args):

  # have all workers write their results to a common outfile
  with open('/scratch365/dduhaime/celery-test.txt', 'a') as out:
    out.write('-'.join([str(i).strip() for i in args]) + '\n')
```

Next I defined a function `schedule_work.py` that schedules the work to be done:

```
'''Worker node; executes tasks outlined in app.py'''
from app import log

# run the add function and pass in arguments
for i in range(10000):
  print('* processing', i)

  result = log.apply_async(args=[str(i)]).get()
```

This file creates 10,000 units of work to do, and passes each integer 0:10000-1 to the work queue. As workers come online, they'll process this queue.

To add workers, I used my university's supercompute system to create 10 workers, each of which starts the `app.py` file, which will make the worker consume work from the stack. To do so using a Sun Grid Engine queue system (the supercompter I'm working on uses this as a job submission protocol), I saved the following in a file `start_workers.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash
#$ -N celery
#$ -o logs/celery.log
#$ -t 1-10:1
#$ -pe smp 4
#$ -q long
#$ -r y
source ~/.bash_profile
source celery-env/bin/activate
# add a new worker
celery worker -l info -A app
```

I then submitted these jobs (`qsub start_workers.sh`), which started 10 workers, each of which was pulling from the list of work to do. In the end, they all logged their host address and the argument from the list of work to be done to the requested outfile, to which they all had access. As we can see in the result file, different hosts from the set of 10 worker hosts consumed different inputs:

```
# /scratch365/dduhaime/celery-test.txt content
10.32.77.210-0
10.32.77.210-1
10.32.77.132-2
10.32.77.210-3
10.32.77.142-4
10.32.77.132-5
10.32.77.210-6
10.32.77.192-7
10.32.77.116-8
10.32.77.142-9
10.32.77.132-10
...
```